# When I use the forEach method, the browser says that there is no such function; what could it be?

Tags: javascript

How can I fix the problem? What could be the problem.

```
"use srict";

var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

btn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click' , function(){
        item.style.display('none');
    });
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Найти</button>
    <button>Идти</button>
    <button>Что-то</button>  

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the function to work, but in the actual result, the browser says that there is no such function.

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection, and HTMLCollections do not have a `forEach` method. But, on newer browsers, NodeLists do - just use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

But this will only work [on newer browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) (2016+ ish). For backwards compatibility, add a "polyfill" first:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
// ...
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

It looks really hacky, but it works and is fully compatible with how browsers implement `NodeList.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

forEach is an Array method that we can use to execute a function on each element in an array. It can only be used on Arrays, Maps, and Sets.

Answer (score 0):

try using [spread operator:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
var btn = [...document.getElementsByTagName("button")];
```